# addEventListener in for loop only work for last element

Tags: javascript

I have an array of ID's linked to inputs. I want to add even listeners to each id in the array but my code is only working for the last ID.

```
        var inputIds = ['flightTotalTime',
            'nightauto',
            'ifrflighttime',
            'simifrauto',
            'picauto',
            'coauto',
            'dualauto',
            'instructorauto',
            'xauto',
            'multiauto',
            'simtimeTotal',
            'seall',
            'meall',
            'sepicday',
            'sedualday',
            'mepicdaypic',
            'medualday',
            'sepicnight',
            'sedualnight',
            'mepicnight',
            'mejet',
            'seturbo',
            'meturbo',
            'lightwake',
            'mediumwake',
            'heavywake',
        ];

        //Add event listener
        for (var o in inputIds) {
            document.getElementById(inputIds[o]).addEventListener('ionBlur', function () {
                validateTime(inputIds[o]);
            }, false);

            document.getElementById(inputIds[o]).addEventListener('ionChange', function () {
                filterChar(inputIds[o]);
            }, false);
        }
```

Wondering if anyone has any ideas how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: try addEventListener('ionBlur', ()=>